# Basis of a Boolean Algebra

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra

I have a construct that I proved forms a (finite) Boolean Algebra of sets over a given universe.

My questions are as follows:

1. Do I immediately know that there exists a unique basis for it?
2. If yes, is there a generic way of constructing it?
3. Given the finiteness property, I know my algebra is atomic.
   Are these atoms precisely all the elements of my basis?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your definition of a "basis" of a Boolean algebra? It is definitely true that any finite boolean algebra is isomorphic to the boolean algebra of subsets of the atoms.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! I had the standard definition of "basis" in mind, i.e: a family of non-empty, pairwise disjoint sets s.t all the sets in the algebra can be seen as a union of basis elements. What do you mean subsets of the atoms? Atoms are non-empty minimal sets, in the sense that they cannot contain any other non-empty set from the algebra.

Comment: There is a set, $A$, of all atoms. The Boolean algebra of all subsets of $A$ is isomorphic to your Boolean algebra. Each atom has no subsets, but the set $A$ does have subsets.

Comment: As for whether this definition is "standard," I didn't find any usage of the term 'basis' relative to Boolean algebras. It doesn't mean that it can't be used that way, but I just haven't seen it used that way, so I doubt it is "standard" so much as your own personal generalization of the term.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The "basis" is indeed the set of all the atoms. I was just curious if there were any well-know (constructive) results wrt this.